# Build uac whitelist for my system

Tags: windows, uac, whitelist

Where I may get whitelist uac binaries (default) for windows 7. I am try looked in msdn, google, but nothing found. I know about this lists 1 and 2, but how he build them...
I whant build same list for my system.

Comment: There are no UAC whitelists in Windows. That is why you are unable to find any information about such a thing.

Answer (score 2):

We would need to know the reason why you want a whilelist. If UAC is enabled, you cannot bypass the UAC prompt, and this is by design. See [FAQ: Why can't I bypass the UAC prompt?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-blog-archive/faq-why-can-8217-t-i-bypass-the-uac-prompt/ba-p/701510) for more information. Excerpt:

> If it were possible to mark an application to run with silently-elevated privileges,
> what would become of all those apps out there with LUA bugs? Answer: they'd all be marked
> to silently elevate. How would future software for Windows be written? Answer: To
> silently elevate. Nobody would actually fix their apps, and end-user applications will
> continue to require and run with full administrative permissions unnecessarily.